# How do I iterate over all filters even if they aren't visible?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I'm trying to change the filter on a column in several tables based on a document property.

I have code that lets me set a visible filter on the current filter scheme, but I don't want to expose the filter to my users. I've found code snippets that let me access a table's filter directly, but I want to basically iterate over the list of tables and set each one's column filter in the background.

```py
page = Application.Document.ActivePageReference

#get the filter panel
filterPanel = page.FilterPanel

for fs in Document.FilteringSchemes:
    if fs.FilteringSelectionReference.Name == "Filtering scheme": 
        filterPanel.FilteringSchemeReference = fs

filterPanel.InteractiveSearchPattern = "UPDATED_DATE"

for myFilter in filterPanel.FiltersMatchingSearchPattern:
    thisFilter = myFilter.FilterReference.As[RangeFilter]()

    if thisFilter != None:
        newLow = Document.Properties['maxdate']
        newHigh = thisFilter.ValueRange.High 
        newRange = ValueRange(newLow,newHigh)
        thisFilter.ValueRange = newRange

filterPanel.InteractiveSearchPattern = ""
```

this doesn't seem to actually change the visible filtering even though sticking print statements in there seems to show that filter values are changed. ideally, i'd do something like

```py
fs1 = Document.FilteringSchemes[Document.ActiveFilteringSelectionReference]

for item in fs1.Item[]:
    if item.Item["UPDATED_DATE"] != None:
        newLow = Document.Properties['maxdate']
        newHigh = item.ValueRange.High 
        newRange = ValueRange(newLow,newHigh)
        item.ValueRange = newRange
```

where i would just go through all the tables in the filtering scheme and set the column, whether it's visible or not.

any help would be greatly appreciated!